# Strange behavior when manipulating char* array in C

Tags: c, linux, shell

I'm trying to create a command line shell for an Operating Systems class. One of our assignments is to create a builtin "history" command that prints out the last 10 commands executed in the shell. Here is the code I have written for the "history" command:

```
char* cmd_hsitory[10]; // This is a global variable

int add_history(char **args) {
  cmd_history[9] = NULL;
  for(int i = 8; i >= 0; i--) {
    cmd_history[i+1] = cmd_history[i];
  }
  cmd_history[0] = *args;
  return 1;
}
```

Where the char **args argument is the last command exectued. Here is the function that prints the history:

```
int lsh_history(char **args) {
  printf("Last 10 commands: \n");
  for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    printf("%s\n", cmd_history[i]);
  }
  return 1;
}
```

Some strange behavior is happening with this code. For instance, when I run the commands [cd, cd, ls, history] in succession, this is the printed output:

```
Last 10 commands:
ls
ls
cd
(null)
(null)
(null)
(null)
(null)
(null)
(null)
```

The first problem here is that I ran the cd command twice, and the ls command only once. If I run the "history" command again I get:

```
Last 10 commands:
history
ls
ls
cd
(null)
(null)
(null)
(null)
(null)
(null)
```

This seems correct with the exception of the 2 ls commands vs the 1 cd command.

This isn't very consistent, though, as sometimes I'll get mixed-up commands and the "history" command will show up several times.

If someone told me what's glaringly wrong with my code, that would be of great help. Thanks!

EDIT: Here is the full source code:
P.s. Most of this code is pulled from the internet (Stephen Brennan) and I'm building on top of it to learn. I will not submit this code as my assignment.

```
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

/*
  Function Declaration for history queue
*/
int add_history(char **args);

/*
  Function Declarations for builtin shell commands:
 */
int lsh_cd(char **args);
int lsh_help(char **args);
int lsh_exit(char **args);
int lsh_history(char **args);

/*
  List of builtin commands, followed by their corresponding functions.
 */
char *builtin_str[] = {
  "cd",
  "help",
  "exit",
  "history"
};

int (*builtin_func[]) (char **) = {
  &lsh_cd,
  &lsh_help,
  &lsh_exit,
  &lsh_history
};

char *cmd_history[10];

int lsh_num_builtins() {
  return sizeof(builtin_str) / sizeof(char *);
}

int add_history(char **args) {
  cmd_history[9] = NULL;
  for(int i = 8; i >= 0; --i) {
    cmd_history[i+1] = cmd_history[i];
  }
  cmd_history[0] = NULL;
  cmd_history[0] = *args;
  return 1;
}

/*
  Builtin function implementations.
*/

/**
  @brief Builtin command: command history.
  @param args List of args. args[0] is "history".
  @return Always returns 1 to continue executing.
*/
int lsh_history(char **args) {
  printf("Last 10 commands: \n");
  for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    printf("%s\n", cmd_history[i]);
  }
  return 1;
}

/**
   @brief Bultin command: change directory.
   @param args List of args.  args[0] is "cd".  args[1] is the directory.
   @return Always returns 1, to continue executing.
 */
int lsh_cd(char **args)
{
  if (args[1] == NULL) {
    chdir("/Users/Landon/");
  } else {
    if (chdir(args[1]) != 0) {
      perror("lsh");
    }
  }
  return 1;
}

/**
   @brief Builtin command: print help.
   @param args List of args.  Not examined.
   @return Always returns 1, to continue executing.
 */
int lsh_help(char **args)
{
  int i;
  printf("Stephen Brennan's LSH\n");
  printf("Type program names and arguments, and hit enter.\n");
  printf("The following are built in:\n");

  for (i = 0; i < lsh_num_builtins(); i++) {
    printf("  %s\n", builtin_str[i]);
  }

  printf("Use the man command for information on other programs.\n");
  return 1;
}

/**
   @brief Builtin command: exit.
   @param args List of args.  Not examined.
   @return Always returns 0, to terminate execution.
 */
int lsh_exit(char **args)
{
  return 0;
}

/**
  @brief Launch a program and wait for it to terminate.
  @param args Null terminated list of arguments (including program).
  @return Always returns 1, to continue execution.
 */
int lsh_launch(char **args)
{
  pid_t pid;
  int status;

  pid = fork();
  if (pid == 0) {
    // Child process
    if (execvp(args[0], args) == -1) {
      perror("lsh");
    }
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  } else if (pid < 0) {
    // Error forking
    perror("lsh");
  } else {
    // Parent process
    do {
      waitpid(pid, &status, WUNTRACED);
    } while (!WIFEXITED(status) && !WIFSIGNALED(status));
  }

  return 1;
}

/**
   @brief Execute shell built-in or launch program.
   @param args Null terminated list of arguments.
   @return 1 if the shell should continue running, 0 if it should terminate
 */
int lsh_execute(char **args)
{
  int i;

  if (args[0] == NULL) {
    // An empty command was entered.
    return 1;
  }

  for (i = 0; i < lsh_num_builtins(); i++) {
    if (strcmp(args[0], builtin_str[i]) == 0) {
      return (*builtin_func[i])(args);
    }
  }

  return lsh_launch(args);
}

#define LSH_RL_BUFSIZE 1024
/**
   @brief Read a line of input from stdin.
   @return The line from stdin.
 */
char *lsh_read_line(void)
{
  int bufsize = LSH_RL_BUFSIZE;
  int position = 0;
  char *buffer = malloc(sizeof(char) * bufsize);
  int c;

  if (!buffer) {
    fprintf(stderr, "lsh: allocation error\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  while (1) {
    // Read a character
    c = getchar();

    if (c == EOF) {
      exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    } else if (c == '\n') {
      buffer[position] = '\0';
      return buffer;
    } else {
      buffer[position] = c;
    }
    position++;

    // If we have exceeded the buffer, reallocate.
    if (position >= bufsize) {
      bufsize += LSH_RL_BUFSIZE;
      buffer = realloc(buffer, bufsize);
      if (!buffer) {
        fprintf(stderr, "lsh: allocation error\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
      }
    }
  }
}

#define LSH_TOK_BUFSIZE 64
#define LSH_TOK_DELIM " \t\r\n\a"
/**
   @brief Split a line into tokens (very naively).
   @param line The line.
   @return Null-terminated array of tokens.
 */
char **lsh_split_line(char *line)
{
  int bufsize = LSH_TOK_BUFSIZE, position = 0;
  char **tokens = malloc(bufsize * sizeof(char*));
  char *token, **tokens_backup;

  if (!tokens) {
    fprintf(stderr, "lsh: allocation error\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  token = strtok(line, LSH_TOK_DELIM);
  while (token != NULL) {
    tokens[position] = token;
    position++;

    if (position >= bufsize) {
      bufsize += LSH_TOK_BUFSIZE;
      tokens_backup = tokens;
      tokens = realloc(tokens, bufsize * sizeof(char*));
      if (!tokens) {
        free(tokens_backup);
        fprintf(stderr, "lsh: allocation error\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
      }
    }

    token = strtok(NULL, LSH_TOK_DELIM);
  }
  tokens[position] = NULL;
  return tokens;
}

/**
   @brief Loop getting input and executing it.
 */
void lsh_loop(void)
{
  char *line;
  char **args;
  int status;

  do {
    printf("> ");
    line = lsh_read_line();
    args = lsh_split_line(line);
    status = lsh_execute(args);

    add_history(args);
    free(line);
    free(args);
  } while (status);
}

/**
   @brief Main entry point.
   @param argc Argument count.
   @param argv Argument vector.
   @return status code
 */
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  // Load config files, if any.

  // Run command loop.
  lsh_loop();

  // Perform any shutdown/cleanup.

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: The problem might comes from somewhere else then those two functions. Please let us see full source code (or at least how you get and pass arguments to those functions)

Comment: You need to show how you call these functions. The assignment of `*args` is fishy.

Comment: Your are storing pointers. Are you sure you are not changing the memory they point to?

Comment: Probably: `add_history(args); free(line); free(args);` The few commands printed correctly are an unhappy accident. You'll need to take a copy of the commands, and this too is an ideal use case for a ring buffer.

Comment: I don't see where you're allocating any memory to store these history strings.

Comment: As well as other problems mentioned, giving null pointer to `%s` is undefined behaviour, you should not rely on doing it and seeing "`(null)`".

Answer (score 0):

You need to strdup() the arg strings over to your cmd_history pointers, not just have your cmd_history pointers reference the original command string. When you free(line), you're putting the memory that your cmd_history pointers are referencing back into the free pool. In the next iteration of the loop you may or may not overwrite that data.

Answer (score 0):

You wrote ((Comments Added)):

```
void lsh_loop(void)
{
  ...
    line = lsh_read_line();       //mallocs line 
    args = lsh_split_line(line);  //mallocs args array; consisting of references into line[]
    status = lsh_execute(args);   //no promblem here

    add_history(args);            // ***PERMANETNLY*** stores args[0] into cmd_history[]!!!
    free(line);                   //frees line[]
    free(args);                   //frees the pointer array into freed line[], which was copied to cmd_history[] --> cmd_history[] points to unallocated memory!!!
}
```

The main problem is related to strtok(): It returns a  pointer into the spitted string, within the original string: If you later free the token pointer array or the original string and **use** it later --> UB. 
Additionally lsh_history() kills also last entry which would leave a memory leak behind, **if** you would allocated that entry firmly.

**Solution:** 
Establish for `cmd_history[]` your own storage of the strings, duplicate and free them properly in `lsh_history()`.